# Fault in Javascript substring matching

Tags: javascript

I am writing a javascript function which basically works like endsWith(),it checks if a string (first argument, str) ends with the given target string (second argument, target).

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  tarLen=target.length;
  strLen=str.length;
  substring = str.slice(strLen-tarLen-1, strLen);
  if(substring==target)
    {return true;}
  else 
    return false;
  
}

confirmEnding("Sangha", "ha");
```

Upon compilation,every time it returns the answer false. But I cannot find any fault in my code. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you see the documentation of [String.prototype.endsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)?  There is a refrence implementation in case your browser doesn't support it yet.

Comment: This is pretty simple to debug really. A piece of paper and a pen would do…

Comment: Use var when you declare new variable. In case of your code tarLen, strLen and substring are considered as globals.

Comment: Sidenote: personally I'd use `'Sangha'.match(/ha$/)`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take away `-1` from your `slice()` function:

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  tarLen=target.length;
  strLen=str.length;
  substring = str.slice(strLen-tarLen, strLen);
  if(substring==target)
    {return true;}
  else 
    return false;
  
}

console.log(confirmEnding("Sangha", "ha"));
console.log(confirmEnding("Sangha", "hda"));
```

Shortened version:

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  var strLen = str.length;
  return target == str.slice(strLen - target.length, strLen);
}

console.log(confirmEnding("Sangha", "ha"));
console.log(confirmEnding("Sangha", "hda"));
```

A version using [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  return str.lastIndexOf(target) == (str.length - target.length);
}

console.log(confirmEnding("Sangha", "ha"));
console.log(confirmEnding("Sangha", "hda"));
console.log(confirmEnding("hahahahahahaha", "ha"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Your slice is wrong, if you check it in the console by typing substring you'll see "gha". You don't need the - 1 in that str.slice. As you want to get all characters until the end of the string, you don't need the second arguments.

Unrelated point, I highly suggest that you declare your vars to prevent them from leaking in the global context.

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  var tarLen=target.length;
  var strLen=str.length;
  var substring = str.slice(strLen-tarLen);
  if(substring==target)
    {return true;}
  else 
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  tarLen=target.length;
  strLen=str.length;

  console.log(tarLen)
  console.log(strLen)

  substring = str.slice(strLen-tarLen, strLen);
  console.log(substring)

  if(substring==target)
    {return true;}
  else 
    return false;

}
```

The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included).
([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice))

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to use -1. I hope following will help

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
   var tarLen=target.length; 
   var strLen=str.length; 
   var substring = str.slice(strLen-tarLen, strLen);  
  if(substring==target)
    {return true;}
  else 
    return false;

}

confirmEnding("Sangha", "ha");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  let result = str.slice(-target.length);
  if (result === target) { 
    return true} else {
      return false}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Rather than just handing over working code, consider explaining how and why it works. Also when answering older questions with existing answers be sure to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses.